# How can I upgrade Angular 4 project to latest version (16)

Tags: angular

I have a project with Angular 4, I want to update the project to the latest version of Angular (Angular 16), how can I do this?

Comment: I would recomennd to do it on major version after another and update it step by step.
Here is a guide what you have to change between the versions: https://update.angular.io/
But that only lkeeps in mind angular itself and not other dependencies you are using

Comment: https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 0):

its quite hard to move from angular 4 to 16 as there are alot of changes made after version 4.  newer versions of Angular have been released with significant improvements and features.
you need to take backup of your existing project and then ,
update the dependencies by using **ng update**
and Resolve Conflicts and Issues

you also need to update modules and api's and specialy the third party library..

Always refer to the official Angular Update Guide and documentation for specific version-specific changes, as the upgrade steps may vary depending on the versions involved.

Remember, upgrading from such an outdated version may be a complex process due to potential breaking changes and deprecated features. Depending on the complexity of your project, it may require significant effort and testing to ensure everything works as expected in the latest version of Angular. Consider consulting with experienced Angular developers if you encounter difficulties during the upgrade process.